# in app billing ServiceConnection is not initialized

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In app purchase in my application. I have follow all steps of given url.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

When I run my code I got null pointer exception in mServiceConn. I have debuge code and found that onServiceConnected() is never called, so serviceconnection is not established.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Please post relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Within hours of trying to find appropriate solution the same problem I was unexpectedly surprised with fixing this issue. I have succesfully completed test purchase after this:

1. **Setting up GoogleApiClient** by this guide - https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html.
   I was getting Google Account ID from Google Plus Services with this client settings:

   ```
       mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
           .addApi(Plus.API)
           .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
           .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
           .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
           .build();
   ```
2. After manually **installing and reinstalling** Google Plus Services - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms
3. **Republish apk** in beta chanel
4. And finally setting access as **beta tester** for my second account through **Google+ Community**